# select row datagrid and display in another datagrid

Tags: datagrid, visual-foxpro, foxpro

when i select the first row it doesn't show only the data of the first row, it shows all the data of the table in the second datagrid

main screen

[main screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOpPu.jpg)

[update screen edit first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65eWE.jpg)

Add the following property to the form in the Init

```
ADDPROPERTY(Thisform,"returnobj", null )
```

in the edit button add the code

```
SELECT (thisform.Grid2.RecordSource) && selects the cursor area of ​​the grid control.
Thisform.ReturnObj = Newobject("Empty")
SCATTER NAME thisform.ReturnObj
Thisform.Release()
```

In the UNLOAD event of the grid form

```
 RETURN Thisform.ReturnedObj
```

when only selecting the second row when editing if the data of the second row appears in the second data grid

[update screen edit second row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Qoj.jpg)

add this code to position the cursor in the first row of the datagrid, when selecting only the first row it appears in the second datagrid but it does not work. Create the property movefirstgrid and its default value will be .F
in the form add to the click event

```
 thisform.movefirstgrid=.T.
 thisform.grdprices.setfocus
```

in the grid add to the setfocus event

```
  if thisform.movefirstgrid
  this.activatecell(1,1)
  endif

  thisform.movefirstgrid=.F.
```

in the second datagrid only the data of the first row is not show, shows all the data that the table has

Comment: Sorry but your question is not understood. Would you care to include sample data\ code  and\or visuals of what you mean.

Comment: I already added the images but it only let me place them as links, it won't let me publish them because I need to have 10 reputation

Comment: Sorry but those screens still doesn't give an idea what you are asking.

Comment: When I select the first row and click the edit button, another screen should open where only the data of the first row should be shown, but in the ReturnObj object all the information of the table is saved and it is shown in the second screen. On the contrary, when I only select the second row, only the second row is shown on the second screen.

Comment: That is not true. ReturnObj only have the record data where pointer is. Can you provide code to reproduce what you are saying.